# How to fix the desktop screen from the cui login screen

Tags: boot, 20.04, login, xorg

OS name: Ubuntu 20.04

After booting and displaying the Ubuntu logo, I got a black screen with a blinking cursor. After switching to the GUI login screen from the information on the net, I entered my account name and password, but could not log in, so I made root the account for login, and the password was not wrong, so I could log in.

I entered the account name:~#startx from the information on the net. Then I got

`/usr/lib/xor: error while loading shared libraries : libpixman-1.so.0: cannot open shared object file: no such file or director.`

I was able to log in to GUI, but what do I have to do to get it to display properly on the desktop screen from here?

Comment: try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^` and reboot. Does that help?